# How to add a class to a GridView using attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, gridview, attributes

i want to add items to a gridview in asp.net from a custom class. The class has Properties X and Y. Does anyone know if im able to add special attributes to these properties so i can just add the class and not have to muck around?

eg..

```
[Column("Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Ideally i can then write something like..

```
this.gridview.datasource = instanceOfMyClass;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a `DataObject` class (equals to `MyClass` in your question)

```
public class DataObject
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The DataSource of the gridview is not an instance of `DataObject` but a `List<DataObject>`(or something equivalent), each `DataObject` refers to one row in the grid view. On the other hand, it's not a good idea to use attributes marked in `DataObject` class. Specifying the `DataField` in the columns of the grid view is the easiest way. Here is an example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And in code behind:

```
List<DataObject> data = GetTheData();
myGridView.DataSource = data;
```